# Azure devops pipeline for Android : No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops

I am new to Azure devops Pipelines and was currently setting up pipeline following the documentations. My builds are failing due to this error

```
No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
```

Agent I use in Azure devops is macos-latest. My yml file content is as given below

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'assembleDebug --info'
```

Can anyone help me fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can install ndk in your pipeline by running this bash task. You can specify ndk version of your choice. In my case 20.x.x was required.

```
- bash: |
   $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;20.0.5594570"
```